# Different margin before and after jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, margin

I have a problem with margin settings during jQuery toggle visibility animation.
It has proper margin-top before it, when I press the button for the animation, it disappears, as it should and when I call it back, it has different margin-top than before. You can look at http://testovaci.mobydyk.cz/enotapp, when you click on "learn more" to show the panel and "learn more" again to close it, original text with the logo has different margin..
How can I solve this? Thank you for all advices, codes are bellow:

HTML:

```
 <div id="slog">
 <span class="txt">
 <div id="mar">
 <p align="center"><img src="logo.png"></p>
 <p align="center">Are you ready for the challenge?<br />
COMING FALL 2015<br /><br /></p>
</div>
</span>
 <p align="center" class="but" onclick="toggle_visibility('txt');" style="display:block; margin-top: 40px;">learn more</p> <br>
    <div class="panel">
  text<br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mar {
margin-top: 7%;
}

#slog {

font-size: 37px;
color: white;
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight:bold;
text-align: center;
}

.panel {
    width: 100%;

  background: gray;
  color: white;

    height: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".but").click(function() {

            $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
      $(".txt").slideToggle("slow");

        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: its the scroll position i guess not the margin that is troubling

Comment: yes. thanks, I've already solved it just by adding "display: block; margin: 0 auto;" to the .txt span :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you found a solution, but I have another advice; it would be better to restructure the entire logic of this document.

First off, don't us two slideToggles at once (on both .txt and .panel). One should be enough. For instance the .panel could have a default position of 100% off the top (so on the bottom of the document), by a div above it pushing it to 100% or either by absolute positioning it. The 'learn more' button can be inside the same container, so it moves up too. Then maken the .panel in a sub-container and somehow with a zero height.

Once you've done this, it's better to use jQuery to just toggle a class on the document (like .toggleClass('show-panel')) This way you can define everything in your css and using css transitions. It will make your animation much more smooth than using jQuery animations, this is especially visible with such big containers.